# execute sh file using node.js on windows OS

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, shell, operating-system

I'm working on node.js application. I'm trying to execute the .sh file from node.js file (on windows operating system) .. but it is throwing error that 'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

File hi.sh

```
echo "Hi There!"
```

File app.js

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var myscript = exec('sh ~/hi.sh');
myscript.stdout.on('data',function(data){
    console.log(data); 
});
myscript.stderr.on('data',function(data){
    console.log(data); 
});
```

Comment: `sh` is not a valid command on windows. To be more precise, you can't expect `sh` to be installed by default. Is it installed on the current machine?

Comment: cant we run sh file on node js?

Comment: Bash is it's own scripting language similar to javascript. In order to run .js files you need node, for .sh files you need additional software.

Answer (score 2):

Windows does not support the Bash scripting language out of the box.

With Windows 10 you can install [**WSL**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about) (Windows Subsystem for Linux), wich gives you Bash support.

After you installed WSL you should be able to use `exec('bash ~/hi.sh');` (not tested), but using it from PowerShell works.

```
PS> bash -c "bash --version"
GNU bash, Version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)[...]
```

Comment: Is there any specific module available in node js to run this script??

Comment: the exec function passes a command to your OS. So your OS needs to handle the execution of the script. This functionality can only be provided by the OS. So you have to install a software like WSL.

Answer (score -1):

On Windows, you can use batch scripts (`.bat` files). So you could have `hi.bat`:

```
echo "Hi There!"
```

and then presumably run this with something like:

```
var myscript = exec('cmd hi.bat');
```